# Error: 'A list ... with the specified title already exists'

Tags: list, content-deployment

We're trying to do content deployment from one SP2010 server to another, and it keeps throwing this error on one of the web sites:

`An unexpected error has occurred.          Lists/FAQ/AllItems.aspx`

`An unexpected error has occurred.          Lists/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

`A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site. Please choose another title.`

We've got two lists on that web site that are called `Forms` and `FAQ`. Those items don't exist on the destination server nor does the web site.

Anyone know how to fix this issue to get content deployment to work? We're running out of time as we approach a deadline to get this site deployed and can **really** use your help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue, but in our case we had run the deployment job previously and it had failed on other errors. We deleted the lists on the Destination Server and re-ran the job and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, Wayferer. That's what we ended up doing too and it fixed it. Hope this helps another poor soul wrestling with this issue :)

Comment: How to delete if list is hidden, kindly suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please make sure these things?

1. Are you sure that you're importing to a blank Site Collection
   template? In other words, destination site collection should be a
   brand new blank site collection – Don't try to export to a newly
   created publishing site collection.
2. Having required features not activated will result in CD failure?
   Also, make sure if there exist any Event handlers which are causing
   the problems
3. If you have multiple errors, then it is best to create a new Site
   Collection at destination and re-run the CD (Import/Export) process.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the webtemp****.xml file to correctly point to the relevant Site Definition.

webtemp****.xml files you will find under C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\1033\XML and the matching ONET.XML fiels you will find under C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates

More Information is available here - http://goo.gl/uxaw8